# Get Logging Output of another Script

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

So basicly I want to start a Script from my Flask Webservice and want to get the Logging output of that Script. Problem is that the called script does not have a class only for logging, logging always happens at the end of a script which is doing something.

Is it possible to catch that Logging output in any way?

EDIT:

for example I have this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# encoding: utf-8

import logHelper as lh
import rest_trigger_configparser as c

lh.init(c.get(c.LOG_PATH), 'CallExternalService_%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M.log',\
   'CallExternalService_%Y_%m_%d_', c.get(c.LOG_LEVEL_NAME))

def thing():
  try:
    print("Nice")
  except Exception as exc:
    lh.logException(str(exc))
```

And now I want to catch that Logexception from another script that starts this one

Comment: Does your script log to a file or to stdout/stderr?

Comment: To a file but I cant now which path it is, since the webservice calls a lot of different scripts which do not save their log paths the same way

Comment: But this script which you want to call. If that's going to put its log into a single file, you can just pick that up once it's done. Can you not?

Comment: The thing is the Webservice cannot know where the log file is located, or can you catch that in any way?

Comment: This is still not clear to me. If you have `c.LOG_PATH`, why don't you just open it and read it after the script is done?

Comment: Cause if I run another script it may save its logs somewhere completly different

Comment: Basicly I have a webservice which takes arguments like scriptname and path of script and runs it. Now I want to check in my webservice script if the runned script is logging something and want to return that logging. But since every script could save its logs somewhere else Im asking if there is a way to catch these loggins instead of opening the log file

Comment: Ah. A general way would require some trickery. You could, if on Linux, look inside the `/proc` directory for file descriptors though I don't know how useful that is. If your script is writing to stdout or stderr, you can catch those quite easily.